# Is it possible to get sidewalk width from OpenStreetMap using osmnx or some other way?

Tags: python, networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx, network-analysis

**I am trying to extract the width of all the sidewalks in a selected area from OpenStreetMap using osmnx, but I cannot seem to find a solution.** After extensive search I came here to check if this is even possible?

I managed to extract the network length for the walkable area (so I guess this would mean all the sidewalks), but I couldn't find any option/ method to extract the width of the sidewalk in each street of a selected area. In the example below I show how I extracted the length of walkable network in Paris and I stop there. :/

**Can somehow please help out?**

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

# Getting the network graph for walking areas
paris = ox.graph_from_place('Paris, France', network_type='walk')
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(paris, node_size=0, bgcolor='k')

# projecting the graph
walk_proj = ox.project_graph(paris)
walk_nodes_proj = ox.graph_to_gdfs(walk_proj, edges=False)
walk_graph_area_m = walk_nodes_proj.unary_union.convex_hull.area
print('Paris walkable network area in square km:', walk_graph_area_m/1000000)

# show the total length of the network
basic_stats = ox.basic_stats(walk_proj, area=walk_graph_area_m, clean_int_tol=True)
print('Paris walkable network length in km:', basic_stats['street_length_total']/1000)
```

Comment: At least in the US, sometimes cities don't even know the width of all their sidewalks. Also, widths can vary, even in the same street block. So, unless someone has physically measured all the sidewalks (very highly unlikely), I doubt you can get this info from OSM or any other resource.

Comment: OSM sporadically has this data. And where it has it, yes you can get it with OSMnx.